# Salvar todo arquivo CSV no mysql

Tags: python

> Objetivo: Criar um programa em python que ao pegar os dados do arquivo
>   CSV, salve no MySql e gere um gráfico.

O que foi feito até o momento:
Um programa em python, onde o mesmo lê o arquivo e imprime no terminal os dados como teste.

Isso funciona? Sim, está imprimindo os dados corretamente no terminal.

**O problema:
O arquivo tem 27 linhas, cada uma deveria ser inserida no banco de dados. Quando tento inserir, o mesmo só insere a linha 27.**

Segue o código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='1mydb')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open('brazil-microcephaly-2016-01-23-table-1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    zikareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =' ', quotechar ='|')
    zikareader = csv.reader(file('brazil-microcephaly-2016-01-23-table-1.csv'))
    for row in zikareader:
        print('-'.join(row))
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(no, \
        state, cases_under_investigation, cases_confirmed, cases_discarded, cases_reported_total)' \
        'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s")', row)

    mydb.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print "Done"


try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *

def main():
    row_count = sum(1 for row in zikareader)  # fileObject is your csv.reader

    master = Tk()
    master.title("Laboratório de Redes, 6º ADS, 2018/1")

    label_titulo = Label(master, text="Análise dos dados", anchor = N, height = 15, width = 40, font = ("Helvetica", 20))
    label_titulo.pack()

    mainloop()
main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua chamada a `cursor.execute` está fora do bloco do `for`  - simplesmente idente a linha corretamente e o problema deve ser resolvido 
(mas não verifiquei se o restante do programa está correto)

```
for row in zikareader:
    print('-'.join(row))
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(no, \
    state, cases_under_investigation, cases_confirmed, cases_discarded, cases_reported_total)' \
    'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s")', row)
```

Comment: Obrigada, era isso mesmo.

Comment: OBS para outros que tenham o mesmo problema: Os dados estavam sendo inserido no banco de dados com aspas simples, caso queiram retirar as aspas simples, apenas retire as aspas duplas que estão no "%s"